# Bitlocker and an overheated laptop

Tags: bitlocker

I have just enabled bitlocker on a newly installed Windows 7 laptop.

The heat and fan noise are far higher than when I boot off my non-bitlockered Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V disk!

I have a Dell Latitude E6400 with the A19 bios.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the heat / noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) can control the fan speed, but only after the boot is finished.

However, this noise can be correct, because booting involves lots of disk accesses, which are certainly more costly in CPU when the encryption of Bitlocker is not supported by a special hardware chip (some computer models have this if they are specially conceived for Bitlocker).

The only solutions I can see are:

1. Improve the air circulation inside the laptop
2. Stop using Bitlocker
3. If encryption is required, only encrypt your sensitive data, by using a product such as [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

Comment: I felt there wasn't a way to fix Bitlocker.. All your options are valid, although in my case I need BitLocker to comply with corporate policy. Thanks for the answer anyhow!